How do I model this weird logistic growth curve based decay?
I have a magic system where people pull energy from the sun by adding to a collective deficit that the sun pays off by subtracting a value, determined by the magnitude of the deficit, from its energy output(dont think ab the physics, I'm handwaving that). So basically, you cast a spell, and the energy gets added to the deficit of the sun. Then, a portion of the suns output goes towards paying that deficit back. This portion is determined using the current value of the deficit. I used a logistic growth curve to model the rate of change given a starting deficit of value D. Sorry if I explained this poorly.
Edit: deleted half of it and put it back in a more comprehensible format I hope.
Each variable and what they represent:

$d$ = starting value of deficit. Constant.

$S$ = max output of the sun. Constant. Equal to $3.86^26$.

$P(x)$ = the deficit payment at an instant given a value of $x$ representing the current value of the deficit.

$O(x)$ = current output strength given a value of $x$ representing the current value of the deficit.

$D(x)$ = Current value of the deficit over time.


The functions are as follows:

$P(x) = -S/(1+e^{-x}) + S$

$O(x) = S/(1+e^{-x}) - S$

$D(x) = $ ???


I want to find a way to model this deficit's value over time. I need to find out what the equation of $D(x)$ is. I want the graph to look like it's linearly decreasing until the area around the sigmoid midpoint, at which point the slope decreases until the graph has an effective slope of 0, and never crosses the x-axis.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. It sounds like you want a discrete-time alternative to the continuous choice $D=D_0r^{t/\tau}$, e.g. $D=D_0r^{\lfloor t/\tau\rfloor}$. Or have I misunderstood what you need?

What's the behaviour you're trying to model here? It seems odd to have the rate of change over time be a logistic function that depends on the energy deficit.
Is it supposed to be that if you spent all your energy or very nearly, you'll recover slowly due to being burnt out - but if you spent only a tiny amount, you'll also recover slowly because you have nothing to recover? Or does spending only a small amount mean you quickly recover to full energy? Or am I misunderstanding entirely?

@ChristopherWells want to have it be that the amount of energy directed to the deficit increases as the magnitude of the deficit increases, and the rate of this increase is very high to start, until eventually plateauing at just infinitely under the max energy generation of the object. The specific way this works is that every single person is pulling from the energy output of the sun, but transferring the suns power into your hands has an efficiency of around 1W for every 10^-12 Watts from the sun.

@J.G. uhhh. give me a second to remember what that means and I'll get back to you

@procrastanator So the rate of energy generation is at its highest when energy is zero, and gradually reduces over time? As your energy approaches the maximum you can store, the rate of energy generation approaches zero so that you never actually reach the maximum?

Ok I updated it so it makes more sense. Sorry ab the previous formatting. Should make more sense now.

@J.G. still not sure what you mean by that, could you tell me? Sorry, they call me the fool in the business.

@ChristopherWells When I originally posted this function, it was concerned with the amount of energy being directed towards paying off the deficit, not energy generation. So no, it's the inverse of what you said. Energy generation would start off at it's maximum value and decrease to 0 as the value of D increases.

I've spent over 20 minutes trying to understand what you want to achieve and failed. Maybe you could describe precise usecase of your modeling, and then somebody could figure out what you need?

@Esgeriath I want to be able to generate graph showing the value of the deficit over time, given a starting value of d. Sorry idk how to explain it

If x is "the deficit", and D(x) is the "current value of the deficit", then isn't your equation simply D(x) = x?


I used a logistic growth curve to model the rate of change given a starting deficit of value D.

If you know the rate of change of the deficit, then the function that defines the deficit itself is called its integral. Calculating the integral of $\frac{S}{1+e^{x}} - S$ isn't straightforward, but luckily someone's done the tricky part here.

The equation of this graph is $ln(e^x+1)-x$. The general form will look something like $S.ln(e^x+e^C)-Sx$, where you can change the value of C to shift the curve left or right.
